# Downgrade in-app level return an error

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have an app with inapp purchases. I move to auto renew inapp purchase using StoreKit. Everything is working find.

But when I downgrade from a level 3 to a level 1 (or from level 3 to level 2, or from a level 2 to level 1), purchase doesn't working an return : "SKErrorDomain Code=0 “Cannot connect to iTunes Store”. No problem with upgrades.

But sometimes, waiting 10-15 minutes after the first purchase before downgrade is working. But not always.

What I did :

- Use device and not simulator (!)
- Sandbox tester is new and never used on a production env
- Logout every production account from the device
- Change order of products and save

Any idea of what's going on ?

Comment: What do you mean by downgrade from a level 3 to a level 1?

Comment: In app purchase group level

Comment: Did you find a solution, I have the same problem, upgrade is working, however downgrade is showing an error.

Comment: No I didn't found any solution

Comment: Is there any helpful code/screenshots we can look at to help you out?

Comment: @bananibau5 No interesting code, it's a classic in-app purchase, working great except for downgrade.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comment above that I left for you, there was an issue with sandbox server at the time of this question being asked so that could have been an issue. See [See "refer"'s response](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/75063) as well as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43114871/skerrordomain-code-0-cannot-connect-to-itunes-store-in-iap-ios-objective-c) also asked on stackoverflow let me know if you are still experiencing issues.

Comment: Nope sorry this issue is dating from a month ago. I try agin today, it's the same problem.