# SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" in IAP iOS Objective c

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

when i tested IAP for my app, it throws following error

```
Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}
```

i have tried many links related to this problem but nothing helped.
Moreover the "Product Identifier" are also correct and i also created new sandbox user, but no output. Any help would be great.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Are your IAP's or your App "Waiting for review" in iTunes Connect?

Comment: nope..i faced this prob today only previously it worked fine

Comment: Same here, it was working correctly yesterday. It might be an iTunes Connect issue but I haven't found anything related to it yet :/

Comment: we are not one facing this prob today  , check [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/75063) out :P

Comment: Same issue here, may be apple server is down

Comment: I see, thanks guys! At least we know it's not our fault :P

Comment: yeepppp..... :P

Comment: Same here! if anyone find the solution let me know

Comment: Also happening to my team. Let's wait

Comment: Same here, apple iap environment incredible and driving me nuts.

Comment: Me too - worst was that I was implementing IAP into an app for the first time and was going crazy thinking it was me doing something silly... turns out it's Apple's end.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SKErrorDomain Code=0 in In-App Purchase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43112171/skerrordomain-code-0-in-in-app-purchase)

Comment: @Pang does that question provides relevant answers..!!??

Comment: I have the same problem. Also my app was rejected because of this (we were unable to making IAP, they said). All other previous (approved) apps also won't work with IAP, so it's definitely going something strange on the apple side.

Comment: I've just tested in-app purchase for sandbox environment, it's started working again.

Comment: yes, started working again ..

Comment: Anyone facing this issue at current moment??

Comment: Anyone facing this issue ?

Answer (score 10):

Looks like Apple's servers are down for Sandbox environment. Live purchases are working just fine!

Comment: did you tested live purchases.?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Apparently they are down again: https://developer.apple.com/system-status/

Answer (score -3):

**SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased** is not called in Live purchases, Only **SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed** is called but amount has been deducted from user account. Now user should click the restore button to restore the purchased products. We don't know the solution for this. Now It is the big headache for all the IOS developers. Apple's servers are down for Sandbox environment.

Comment: `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased is not called in Live purchases` is a very dangerous claim I would say. I am now testing the purchases in Sandbox and I am getting the `.purchased` state. Are you saying that this is not the case in Live purchases?