# IAP AutoRenewing Sandbox Account - Cannot Connect to iTunes Store error

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, rmstore

Sorry to be adding another to the IAP sandbox pile...

Is this still any issue? [SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" in IAP iOS Objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43114871/skerrordomain-code-0-cannot-connect-to-itunes-store-in-iap-ios-objective-c)

I see that its green on https://developer.apple.com/system-status/

However, I continue to get the error.

i am logged out of my real AppleId
Press button to purchase autorenewing item
Authenticate with a new sandbox account.
Authentication seems to pass fine and the Subscription Terms window with product displays fine.
Press Continue and it ends with the error: Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"
Is your implementation working now?

UDPATE

I went into my restore purchases function and used that sandbox account to successfully restore the purchase. Soooooo its processing but not posting the correct codes back? Ever see this before?
ps - would be helpful for any votes. I would have left a comment but havent got any rep yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally working (I hope for good).

I reset my device settings. 
I created a new itunes sandbox account.

It works!

Note: For some reason the sandbox accounts aren't letting me use the + trick so I had to use a new, unregistered.